# Using vstest.consol.exe to run Moq unit tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, moq, vstest

I have used Moq in my unit tests in Visual Studio 2013. I need to run the test cases in Command-line using "vstest.console.exe".

When trying to do so, I get this error:

> Error: An exception occurred while invoking executor 'executor://mstestadapter/v1': Could not load file or assembly 'Codex.Repository, verion=1.0.0.0, Clture-neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is the command I use to run tests:

```
vstest.console.exe "C:.../Codex.repository.unittests.dll" /UseVsixVersion /Framework:framework45
```

When trying to execute the test cases individualy using "/Tests:" tag, I got a more detailed error message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Moq, Version=4.2.1502.911, Culture-neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f4...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot fild the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: there is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

So now I know the reason is using Moq in my test cases.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally I was using the unit test dll file in the obj folder:

```
c:\>vstest.console.exe "..\obj\release\unittests.dll"
```

Visual Studio puts all dependent .dll files in the bin folder so I changed to:

```
c:\>vstest.console.exe "..\bin\release\unittests.dll"
```

Problem solved!

Comment: If you also have Visual Studio on the same node you can run a long running test and then try to use process explorer to find out which  folder the test dll is being loaded from. Then use Vstest.console.exe to load tests from that dll. You will no longer get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure these dependencies are set to "Copy Local = True" that way `vstest.console` will be able to find them alongside your test assembly.